# Batch dot product with numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, tensordot

I need to get the dot product of many vectors with one vector. Example code:

```
a = np.array([0, 1, 2])

b = np.array([
    [0, 1, 2],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [-1, 0, 1],
    [-3, -2, 1]
])
```

I would like to get the dot product of each row of `b` against `a`. I can iterate:

```
result = []
for row in b:
    result.append(np.dot(row, a))

print(result)
```

which gives:

`[5, 17, 2, 0]`

How can I get this without iterating? Thanks!

Comment: This is just a matrix multiplication `b @ a`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `numpy.dot` or `numpy.matmul` without `for` loop:

```
import numpy as np

np.matmul(b, a)
# or
np.dot(b, a)
```

Output:

```
array([ 5, 17,  2,  0])
```

Comment: Wow, not sure how I overlooked that solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I will just do `@`

```
b@a
Out[108]: array([ 5, 17,  2,  0])
```

Answer (score 0):

can be useful if you need to line by line multiply two arrays of vectors

```
np.sum(a * b, axis=1)
```